# Could not find or load main class java hello world

Tags: java

I am trying to write **hello world** on java. My code is:

```
class myfirstjavaprog
{  
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

And when I run **java youtube.java** on cmd I got this error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class youtube.java**

Comment: `java myfirstjavaprog`.....

Comment: not worked I got same error

Comment: how? I am just saving in notepad++ and then runing with cmd:
**java youtube.java**

Comment: Reimeus I got this:
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @DilaraAliyeva You need to have the JDK installed to compile applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile the class java with `cmd` use:

```
  javac youtube.java
```

But if you want to run it use this:

```
  java youtube
```

If you have error with command `javac` check your `Environment Variables`.

Comment: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @DilaraAliyeva try to Environment Variables like above

Answer (score 0):

In Java the name of the public class has to be the same as the source file or you will get that error. Try changing the first line to `class youtube`.

Comment: Not worked :(
`class youtube
{  
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}`

Comment: Yeah, try compiling it with `javac` as Abdelhak suggested.

Comment: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You don't have the JDK (Java Development Kit) installed on your computer then. Without it, you won't be able to compile or run your java programs. See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: I have installed JDK

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

Assuming your file name is `youtube.java`,

Run the following:

```
javac youtube.java
```

Once it compiles, it should generate a `myfirstjavaprog.class` file.

To execute this class, you need to run the following command:

```
java myfirstjavaprog
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to set JDK into your path variable in windows.

Comment: Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment variables. In that dialog, add your "C:\_PATH_TO_JDK\bin" to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that issue is when you try to run application on older JRE, that is compiled with newer Java version. Check your java version, then compile code according to it. If you are using Eclipse, you can change that on configure build path option.